# A trigger making a timestamp of when another column was changed

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-12c

I've beeen trying to create a trigger, that'll make a timestamp, of when our account was "deleted" which we do by setting deleted = 1. Below code creates a trigger for that purporse, however it has compilation errors and doesn't work.

So i wanna update the column DELETEDTIME with the the current sysdate timestamp of when deleted was set equal to 1, however i can't see where i've gone wrong in the code below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_deletiontime 
AFTER UPDATE 
OF DELETED ON VTIGER_CRMENTITY
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.DELETED = 0 AND old.DELETEDTIME = NULL)
BEGIN
new.DELETEDTIME := sysdate()
END;
```

Error from sys.user_errors says "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END", however no amount of ; or / seems to fix this

Answer (score 1):

- Semicolon is missing after `sysdate()`.
- `new` should be `:new`.
- You can not assign values to `:new` in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, becasue it fires after the update, the value is already updated. So I changed it to `BEFORE UPDATE`.

> ```
> create table vtiger_crmentity (deleted number, deletedtime date);
>
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_deletiontime 
> BEFORE UPDATE 
> OF DELETED ON VTIGER_CRMENTITY
> FOR EACH ROW
> WHEN (old.DELETED = 0 AND old.DELETEDTIME is NULL)
> BEGIN
> :new.DELETEDTIME := sysdate();
> END;
> /
> ```

Comment: When i add a semicolon after sydate, my software percieves the command me trying to run 2 sql statements, where then 2nd simply being the line END;

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I did not catch that. Fixed it.

Comment: I don't know if you should skip `()`, i.e. `:new.DELETEDTIME := sysdate;`

Comment: with above code, AQT (Advanced Query Tool) believes im writing 3 different statements, because END; and / are seperated from the query with the semicolon after sysdate

Comment: Looking at the [AQT Feature List](http://querytool.com/features.html) it seems to support querying (obvs) and indirectly [other DML statements](http://querytool.com/features/tour6.html) but there's no mention of DDL. So it seems if you want to change the schema you'll need to use a different tool.